# ionic3 api: response with status: 0 for url: null Only on device

Tags: php, android, api, ionic3

I have imported following module

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Http,Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
```

and i have set in headers are

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

and make call like this

```
this.apiUrl ="some api url here";

return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'user-details.php?e='+email+'&p='+password,{headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

it's working good on browser and returns result
But when i run on device it shows error as "response with status: 0 for url: null".
please guide me to fix this issue

Comment: Have you enabled `wifi` on your device?

Comment: Yes off course i have enabled